# Regex to find and replace any word that is not after another word

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm currently running a simple find-and-replace, on strings like this:

```
1. User.Name "John"
2. User.Age 20
3. Name.Length 5
```

However, trying to replace `Name` with `WHATEVER` results in this:

```
1. User.WHATEVER "John"
2. User.Age 20
3. WHATEVER.Length 5
```

I needed to change line 3, but not line 1. How do I check if the current word is after a dot (`.`) and skip replacing that word?

I'm in .NET 4.0 and my regex currently looks like this:

```
result = new Regex(@"\b" + oldWord + @"\b").Replace(text, newWord);
```

Comment: To be honest, I think REGEX is way overused. There are so many easy solutions like string.StartsWith()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on `.`: `(?<!\.)`

That gives:

```
result = new Regex(@"\b(?<!\.)" + oldWord + @"\b").Replace(text, newWord);
```

Comment: So in order to skip if prev word is "BADDIE" I would write this? -- `(@"\b(?<!BADDIE)" + oldWord + @"\b")`

Comment: @Geotarget: `(?<!BADDIE)Name` matches `BADDIE Name`, `Name` but not `BADDIEName`. I suggest you go experiment on [My Regex Tester](http://myregextester.com). Click on "Highlighted matches" to see where a regex matches.